# How to traverse an object in Javascript in loop which is not linear

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object with structure as below:

```
group[0] = [Object {code: 1}, {code: 2}, {... and so on}]
group[1] = [Object {code: 3}, {code: 4}, {... and so on}]
group[2] = [Object {code: 3}, {code: 4}, {... and so on}]
group[3] = [Object {code: 3}, {code: 4}, {... and so on}]
group[4] = [Object {code: 3}, {code: 4}, {... and so on}]
```

In case 1: My group.length gives me 5 and I can traverse as

```
for(i=0;i<group.length; i++) {}
```

But if I delete any particular entry say the second one then the structure becomes as

```
group[0] = [Object {code: 1}, {code: 2}, {... and so on}]
group[2] = [Object {code: 3}, {code: 4}, {... and so on}]
group[3] = [Object {code: 3}, {code: 4}, {... and so on}]
group[4] = [Object {code: 3}, {code: 4}, {... and so on}]
```

Because of some limitation I can't change the number of other groups and now my group.length is 4 so if I put a for loop it gives error for group[1] case as it becomes undefined.

Please give me a solution so that i can bypass the undefined values

Comment: When you say delete, how are you deleting? With `delete group[1]` or by splicing?

Comment: Also, you don't state at what point you are deleting the value. Do you mean inside the for loop? As in, removing itself during the loop? If so, DickieBoy's answer is probably the right one regarding caching the length value

Comment: if `group` as you said is an object then you could use a `for (key in group) { ... }`

Comment: hold on a second... Are you modifying the array from within the loop?

Comment: Seeing how frequently edits are being made in the answers, it can be said that the question is very confusingly worded. Can you make your question more clear? **Are you deleting array elements from within the loop during iteration?** or **Are you just iterating over the array with undefined elements within it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `group.length` is being re-evaluated when you remove an element from the array. Do this:

```
group_length = group.length
for(i=0;i<group_length; i++) {}
```

Edit: This assumes that you are deleting elements in the array from within the loop. If not, then disregard.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably how you're deleting the entry. Try using the splice command instead, so `group.splice(x, 1)` where x is the element you want to remove.

Then `group.length` will adjust to the new size of the array.

**EDIT:**
So, taking into account the feedback in the comment, how about something along the lines of

```
for(i=0;i<group.length; i++) {
  if(!group[i]) {
    continue;
  }
  //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I cannot use splice to delete as I don't need to shift the objects from group[2] to group[1] position. And thus the length of the group will become 4 but I wan't to got to the next value.

Comment: Accepted but the number of iterations is still one less

Comment: If reiterating. group.length will return 4. Your condition is i<group.length. So you can have i max to 3. You wont be able to access group[4] through this loop condition.

Comment: Only because of the continue. You can remove the continue and do something else if group[x] is falsy. Or am I completely misunderstanding what you're actually after?

Answer (score 0):

Guys I Finally had to add a counter and solve it without removing my entries.
Thanks for all help

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution,

```
for(i in group){  // i will return only valid indexes.
    console.log(group[i]);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw5u8zvc/2/)

Comment: that's fine. but for group[1] it is saying that group is not defined and giving error

Comment: @VaibhavSah `i` will never return 1. It will only return valid indexes, in your case 0,2,3,4